# How to add pending column in grid view

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to add "pending" column

There are two tables "document" and "approval"

I show document table in grid view but here I want to add one more column that is "pending" column

Just like this

```
docid docname file documnettype deptype status
1    abc      abc.pdf  pdf        finance  pending
```

I want to add column which is "pending" when a user uploads document then its status automatically show as pending.

In the "approval" table there is approve,reject and pending

```
create procedure sppendingfilesss
as
    select  DocumentInfo.DepID,DocumentInfo.DocName,DocumentInfo.Uploadfile,DocType.DocType,Department.         DepType,ApproveType.ApproveType
    from DocumentInfo inner join DocType on   
         DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=DocType.DocTypeID       
    inner join Department on DocumentInfo.DepID=Department.DepID
    inner join ApproveType  on DocumentInfo.ApproveID=ApproveType.ApproveID  and    
         (ApproveType.ApproveType=2)
```

any solution

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a very hard time trying to figure out what, exactly, you're asking.

Comment: i try to ask how to add pending column in grid view through storeprocedure

Answer (score 0):

??? Are you talking about:

```
alter table ApproveType
    add [Status] varchar(10) null 
    constraint default_Pending default 'pending';
```

Comment: i want to add a column pending in gridview through store procedure..means that when any user upload document then in grid-view automatically status display as pending the above query which i posted as a show upload documents now in this i want to add pending status i have a separate approve type table in which approveid ,approvetype(1 approve 2 reject ,3 pending) ...and i show pedning in grdiview .